# firebase phone authentication (confirm is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

What is wrong in this code?

```
import { auth } from '../firebase-config'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber} from 'firebase/auth'
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-input-2';

const Profile = ({isLoggedIn}) => {

  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState('');
  const [confirmationResult, setConfirmationResult] = useState(null);

  const sendOtp = async ()=>{
    try {
          const recaptcha = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth,"recaptcha",{});
          const confirmation = signInWithPhoneNumber(auth,phoneNumber,recaptcha);
          setConfirmationResult(confirmation);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  const verifyOtp =async()=>{
    try {
      await confirmationResult.confirm(otp)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error "+ error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {}
      <div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <PhoneInput
        country={"in"}
        value={phoneNumber}
        onChange={(phone)=>setPhoneNumber("+" + phone)}
        />      </div>
      <div id="recaptcha"></div>
      <button onClick={sendOtp}>send otp</button>
      <div>
          <input type="text" value={otp} onChange={(e) => setOtp(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <button onClick={verifyOtp}>verify otp</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

I am getting this error:

> confirmationResult.confirm is not a funcion

Comment: The question is a bit vague but the error is fairly clear; `confirmationResult` is not a function so this `await confirmationResult.confirm(otp)` throws an error. `setConfirmationResult` sounds more like a function.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `await` or `then` in your code:

```
signInWithPhoneNumber(auth,phoneNumber,recaptcha).then((confirmation) => {
  setConfirmationResult(confirmation);
});
```

This is pretty much straight up from the documentation on [sending a verification code to the user's phone](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone), so I recommend keeping that handy.